# please HELP, Best/efficient way to deploy MERN ecommerce for production

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, digital-ocean, mern

i've just build a multivendor ecommerce webapp using mern stack its a giant project

Now i want to deploy this webapp on digital ocean

Now i just want to know how do i deploy like deploy directly on digital ocean using nginx firewall etc
Or
Should i use docker/kubernetes then after containerization go for digital ocean

Or

If you know a better way to deploy im open to suggestions

-i'll be using two servers one for mongodb and other for react and node,If you think if im doing it wrong please correct me

-or should i use 3 server  for backend,frontend and mongodb respectively

-what's your opinion how should i do things

This webapp is going to get around  5000-10000
Per day visits

Last question should i use one git repo like combined backend+fronent
Or should i use two repo for frontend and backend

Any suggestion on folder structure for this big webapp

Please help im really stuck and confuse

Thank you

Which is bettet structure  A or B
[image: structure A]

[image: structure B]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesnt fully cover your question in depth, my recommendation for an  easy environment would be to use the Digital Ocean app platform for your frontend and backend. Use two seperate repositories to get automatic CI/CD.
https://www.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/

And then their managed Mongoose instance.

There is a bit more knowledge that goes into properly operating a complex site like that. But this will get you started with a self-maintaining environment, that does not allow for VPS configurations errors, comes at a cheap price and automates most of the basic DevSecOps tasks for you.

Be sure to put secrets in the app environment and not in commited files.

Alternatively, you could use their managed Kubernetes.